# Azure PullAudioInputStream Not working accurately with Twilio Voice

Tags: azure, audio, twilio, azure-cognitive-services

I integrated Twilio Media stream with Azure Cognitive service (Speech to Text). I inherited `speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback` class to send audio chunks to server.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import queue

class SocketReaderCallback(speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._q = queue.Queue()

    def read(self, buffer: memoryview) -> int:
        chunk = self._q.get()
        buffer[:len(chunk)] = chunk
        return len(chunk)

    def has_bytes(self):
        return True if self._q.qsize() > 0 else False

    def queueup(self,chunk):
        self._q.put(chunk)

    def close(self):
        print("AZ.Callback.Closed")
```

Below is code for transcriber class. Here `add_request` method adds audio chunks to Queue of above callback class. callback class picks chunks from queue and uploads to Azure server for transcription.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import queue
from rule_engine.medium.azure_transcribe.azure_calback import SocketReaderCallback

class AzureTranscribe:

    def __init__(self, speech_config, on_response, user_id):
        self._on_response = on_response
        self.callback = SocketReaderCallback()
        wave_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(samples_per_second=8000, bits_per_sample=8, channels=1)
        self._stream = speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStream(self.callback,wave_format)
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=self._stream)
        self._speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, language="en-IN", audio_config=audio_config)
        self._ended = False
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.initialize_once()
        self.state = None

    def initialize_once(self):
        # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
        self._speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('AZ.RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
        self._speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('AZ.RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
        self._speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('AZ.SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
        self._speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('AZ.SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
        self._speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('AZ.CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
        self._speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

    def add_request(self, buffer):
        # buffer, self.state =  audioop.ratecv(bytes(buffer), 2, 2, 8000, 16000, self.state)
        self.callback.queueup(bytes(buffer))
    
    def terminate(self):    
        self._ended = True
        self._speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
```

- If I upload audio chunks from an audio file, the transcription is
  accurate.
- If I upload audio chunks from twilio call, transcription is
  very bad.

> Twilio's sample rate is 8 kHz while Azure's expected    sample rate
> is 16 kHz. Yet Azure works with both sample rates and    provides poor
> quality transcription for both.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the input audio file format that you are sending from the Twilio.

Comment: Hi HarshIT,

Were you able to get this working . I'm using speech translation and even with the recommended audio config I couldnt get anywhere . Appreciate your feedback. 

My Code : https://gist.github.com/rajeshr6r/349d32e9b565159fe07e1dfc80f5b1d2
My Error Log : https://gist.github.com/rajeshr6r/69ab3a2b8442ffd6117aa346b648b2bf

Comment: No luck. I dropped Azure integration as they don't have clear documentation or sample code. Azure servers are super costly if you forget to shutdown. Azure's console is worse than Edge browser (reskinned Internet Explorer).